# Generate pseudo random test with Scalacheck

Tags: scala, automated-tests, scalatest, scalacheck

I want to test my code with **Property based** testing style.
I have some generator, that always generates `Some(data)`, the data is never filtered out.
I want to run let's say 100 tests, with the same set of data across the runs. Now, I'm doing it like this, but it is not very idiomatic code:

```
import org.scalacheck._
import java.util.Random
import org.scalatest._

class ExplainItOnStackOverflow extends PropSpec {
  property("Just a test property to explain my problem!") {
    val g = Gen.choose(1,100)
    for (i <- 1 to 100) {
      val Some(res) = g.apply(Gen.Params(rng = new Random(i)))
      assert (res > 0)
    }
  }
}
```

The class `PropSpec` has it's own method `runAll`, it seems to me like I should want to use it to run these property checks.